# Is it possible to store ArrayList index into Struts 2 selectbox as listkey?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, arraylist

I have a Struts2 application. On jsp page I use selectbox to populate ArrayList from database:

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryId" listValue="countryName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Country" label="Select country" />
```

But I need to store in listKey not an *id* but index of ArrayList. So then I read this index, find the appropriate country in ArrayList and retrieve it.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `countryList.indexOf(country)` as below:

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryList.indexOf(country)" 
                                           listValue="countryName" headerKey="0"  
                                   headerValue="Country" label="Select country"/>
```

Comment: Note that while it likely doesn't matter, this is a pretty expensive operation since it will iterate over the list to find the country. IMO it would be better to look it up after submission, performing the lookup only once, or create an index/country list on the Java side, etc.